# Most efficient way to do this PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, processing-efficiency

I have any number of users in a database (this could be 100, 2000, or 3) what i'm doing is using mysql "show tables" and storing the table names in an array, then i'm running a while loop and taking every table name (the user's name) and inserting it into some code, then i'm running said piece of code for every table name. With 3 users, this script takes around 20 seconds. It uses the Twitter API and does some mysql inserts. Is this the most efficient way to do it or not?

Comment: So each user gets their own table?

Comment: yes, is this not right? I didnt want to mingle the users within one table

Comment: Why do you have a separate table for every user? Is this because of Twitter? You rep suggests you wouldn't likely design such a system on your own.

Comment: May I echo what the others have said by remarking, "Jesus Christ".

Comment: why would i mingle say 200+ users within one table? my rep? whats that got to do with anything and yes i'm attempting this on my own :)

Comment: @benhowdle89 You do want to mingle the users in one table. You want to use indexes and joins and stuff so that your recordset doesn't care about this. A user isn't a "fixed concept", and tables represent fixed concepts: a set of maps of property names to their values. A "user" is data, not metadata.

Comment: @benhowdle89 I think your mistake is thinking of a DBMS like a person that reads through a table. It may be that when reading through a list of data, you find it irritating having different users mixed up in it. The way to solve this would be sorting. For a computer, though, it's not even a problem. You definitely, definitely should not be doing what you're doing.

Comment: I welcome advice, because as you may see i'm no DB admin, but if you could make me feel less of a tit, that would be great :)

Comment: A table can have billions of rows. A database can only reasonably have hundreds/thousands of tables and reading information about tables is very expensive.

Comment: hmmm...didnt realise that. Well by the answers of people screaming at me, i now do :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly not!

I don't understand why you store each user in their table. You should create a `users` table and select from there.

It will run in 0.0001 seconds.

Update:

A table has rows and columns. You can store multiple users in rows, and information about each user in columns.

Please try some database design tutorials/books, they wil help you a great deal.

Comment: i have done it this way because, each user has a column called tweet_id and tweet. how would i do this but with one table called users??

Comment: I'll up this, and just add, look into general database design. It may surprise some other developers but I've actually heard of others coming up with this design idea before. Honestly, I'm not sure where this idea stems from other than a lack of understanding surrounding joins between tables, but alas, this is the absolutely best answer going. I can think of no production system in the world that would create tables for every single user. It is madness.

Answer (score 0):

If your worried about storing multiple entries for each user within the same users table, you can have a seperate table for tweets with the **tweet_id** refering to the user.

I'd certainly go for one users table.

Comment: ok that sounds good. I suppose much better than a table for each

Answer (score 0):

Databases are optimized for processing  many rows; some of the techniques used are indexes, physical layout of data on disk and so on. Operations on many tables will be always be slower - this is just not what RDBMS were built to do.

There is one exception - sometimes you optimize databases by sharding (partitioning data), but this approach has as many advantages as disadvantages. One of the disadvantages is that queries like the one you described take a lot of time.

You should put all your users in one table, because, from logical point of view - they represent one entity.